# jquery ajax script is run successfully but results in error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a simple script that keeps resulting in error, even though the PHP script is run successfully.

**PHP**

```
require('/connect.php');  //Has my $link variable


if(isset($_POST['pass'])){

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $oldpass = md5(urldecode($_POST['op']));
    $newpass = md5(urldecode($_POST['np']));

    $q = "SELECT * FROM `nht_users` WHERE usr = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$oldpass."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($link,$q);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($r);

    if( $n > 0){

        $u = "UPDATE `nht_users` SET pass = '".$newpass."' WHERE usr = '".$user."'";
        mysqli_query($link,$u);

    }

    else{

        echo json_encode('FALSE');

    }

}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#pass-submit').click(function() {

        var npp = $('#npp').val(),
            np = $('#np').val(),
            data = $('#pass-form').serialize(),
            url = 'http://www.<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>/functions.php';

        if (npp == np) {
            $('#test').html(url);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: 'pass=true&'+data,
                success: function(data){

                    $('#pass-form').slideUp(800);
                    $('.pass-true').fadeIn(800);

                },
                error: function(){

                    $('.pass-false').fadeIn(800);

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.pass-check').fadeIn(800);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you send headers from the script?

Comment: Is the error in your browser console?

Comment: Sorry, It does the AJAX error callback.

Comment: @tPlummer error is because you haven't echo anything when update query runs or it occurs in the if check

Comment: I suggest adding some `echo` statements at strategic places throughout your php file to help track what's going on. Incidentally, it seems that you'll want a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

To catch the error

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: See, that's the thing.  If I program it for that, there is no response text.

Comment: @tPlummer that means your php isn't returning anything. My guess is you're actually getting a 500 error (Internal Server Error) which would indicate a php error. What do the textStatus and errorThrown parameters contain?

Answer (score 0):

To get a better idea of what is happening in your response, you can try to use the network tab in Chrome (hit F12) and run your process. You should see your ajax request and response come through. Internet Explorer also has a similar option, but you will need to tell it to explicitly watch the network. One other option for tracing this type of issue is to install a desktop application like Fiddler2 (http://fiddler2.com/).

I have used all 3 of these to varying levels to hunt down why my AJAX requests are not running as expected.